# Maximum Network Flow with Definition

Tags: algorithm, graph

recently i get stuck in problem. i reading the Network Flow book for fun !

> i couldn't prove which of the following are true? and which false? and why?
>
> > I would be so glad if everyone could help me !

in maximum network flow which of theses sentence be correct?

a.  If x is a maximum flow, either xij  = 0 or xji  = 0 for every arc (i, j) ∈  A.

b.  Any network always has a maximum flow x such that xij  = 0 or xji = 0 for all (i, j) ∈ A.

Comment: reading about network flows for fun and got stuck at the exercises... sure...

Answer (score 1):

For any arc (i, j) you can change (xij, xji) to (xij + D, xji + D), note that D could also be negative. This is simply because you can circulate arbitrary amounts of flow between i and j (it stays between the two, never flowing into the rest of the network).

Thus a) is false, and b) is true, because if xij != 0 and xji != 0 you can take D to be -min(xij, xji) and modify the arc flow to turn one of them into 0.

Comment: Let S be the source and T be the sink, and let there be two additional nodes, A and B, with network topology S -(1)- A -(3)- B -(1)- T. (simple linear graph, the values in parentheses are the capacities). The maxflow is equal to 1, for example with xSA = 1, xAB = 1, xBT = 1, all others 0. But you can also have xAB = 2, xBA = 1, or xAB = 3 and xBA = 2, it still satisfies the equations.